# reverse a string from a stack

Tags: arrays, stack

Today I submitted a answer for reversing the string and I just swap the first element with the last, and repeating until it reaches the middle. My professor posted a stack ADT solution which I don't quite understand. I think it's because I am very new to data structures so I am looking for some insights

Comment: Generally, if you have a stack of something, and then you take the top item and place it into a new stack, and continue this way until there are no more items in the original stack, you would have reversed the stack. What language was your professor using to teach and did he use one array or two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say some string

```
lmao
```

after you push every character to a stack, the stack becomes

```
o
a
m
l
```

after you pop the stack (always pop the top element) until it's empty. You get back

```
oaml
```

, which is the reverse of the original string

Comment: thank you for answering. My friend gave me a clear explanation earlier